# Has anyone noticed that a WPF file dialog will pass a click through to the UI when double clicking to select a file?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, openfiledialog, double-click, savefiledialog

I have some buttons on my WPF UI and I also need to choose files from time to time.  I kept noticing strange problems where when I double-click an item in the file dialog, a button on the main UI would also get clicked.  After experimenting, it seems that if you line up an item in the file dialog with a button behind it on the main UI and double click to select the file, it will single-click the button behind it as well.

Has anyone else noticed this, or is it just a freak bug with the way I have my UI laid out?

Comment: have you used snoop to find out exactly what is going on?

Comment: All I see in Snoop is that the button handled a click event.  The OpenFileDialog is literally allowing the second click of the double-click to pass through to the UI.

Comment: Interesting, consider reporting on Windowsclient.net.

Comment: I have the same problem with Silverlight 4. Do anyone know what is going on? How to mitigate this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick to solve this, hope still helps:

[Mouse left button up event and openfiledialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005027/mouse-left-button-up-event-and-openfiledialog/3005601#3005601)

Regards